# display: inline-block & truly liquid layouts

Tags: css

I have three `inline-block` divs, with well-defined widths. (They are a nav bar, a toolbar, and the app's banner, respectively.)

When the page is wide, we need them to go:

```
[a][b][c]
```

Easy enough. But when the page is narrow (going mobile), they should go:

```
[c]
[a]
[b]
```

So, do we have anyone who truly comprehends `float: left` & `right` to help out here?

Comment: Use CSS flexbox — it is designed specifically to allow you to reorder flex elements. Also, sharing some markup would be useful — try porting them over to a fiddle.

Comment: `inline-block` elements do behave that way, don't they? Am I missing something?

Comment: a,b,c turned into c,a,b, guys...

Comment: Are you using float or inline block? Can you make a simple fiddle to show this? something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/j5ULB/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [media query](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).For example

```
div{
 display:inline-block;
 width:33%;
}

@media (max-width: 600px){
 div{
  display:block;
  width:auto;
 }
}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/hNSP8/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's the answer:

```
<div style="border: 1px dashed blue; display: inline-block; ">
  <!-- add width: 3em; to see the "mobile phone" version -->
  <div style="float: right; display: inline-block; width: 2em;">c</div>
  <div style="display: inline-block; width: 2em;">a</div>
  <div style="display: inline-block; width: 2em;">b</div>
</div>
```

Without the `width: 3em;` (simulating a narrow layout), we get ABC. But with the `width: 3em` (or if you scrunch your browser window up), we get CAB.